# Can every bounded sequence be partioned into a set of convergent subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This thought was prompted by thinking about a proof of the Boundedness Theorem for a real analysis module in the second year of a Mathematics BSc course.

\begin{align}
& \text{Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence.} && (1) \\
& \text{Then $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.}  && (2) \\
& \text{Now let $(y_n)=(x_n)\backslash(x_{n_k})$.}  && (3) \\
& \text{Then $(y_n$) is a bounded sequence and so has a convergent subsequence $(y_{n_k})$.}  && (4)
\end{align}

Repeating this process, don't we partition $(x_n)$ into convergent subsequences?

Comment: I think that almost works. Your argument doesn't necessarily exhaust the sequence, but you can make it do so by starting each subsequence construction with the first element not yet used. Note too that your construction isn't optimal. It might make countably many subsequences even from a sequence that converges.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Ethan Bolker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72858/ethan-bolker). I vote for him.

But note that you will not necessarily obtain every limit point of your original sequence as a limit of one of your subsequences. So I think that undermines the usefulness.

For example, consider the sequence $a_n = \sin(n)$ for $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$. Then every point $x \in [-1,1]$ is a limit point of some subsequence. You could get one sequence $\mathfrak{X}^{(1)} = (x^{(1)}_1,x^{(1)}_2,x^{(1)}_3,\dots)$ converging to say $0$, such that $x^{(1)}_1=\sin(1)$. Then you can get a second sequence and a third sequence $\mathfrak{X}^{(i)} =(x^{(i)}_1,x^{(i)}_2,x^{(i)}_3,\dots)$ for $i=2,3$ converging to say $1/2$ and $-1/2$ with $x^{(2)}_1=\sin(k_2)$ where $k_2$ is the smallest $k$ such that $\sin(k)$ is not in $\mathfrak{X}^{(1)}$ (which is necessarily at least $2$) and $x^{(3)}_1=\sin(k_3)$ where $k$ is the smallest $k$ such that $\sin(k)$ is not in $\mathfrak{X}^{(1)}$ or $\mathfrak{X}^{(2)}$ (which is necessarily at least $3$). You could continue in this way to get subsequences converging to all the numbers $0$ and $\pm i/2^n$ for $n \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $i \in \{1,\dots,2^{n-1}\}$. But you will not be able to get all numbers in $[-1,1]$ as limits of these subsequences.

Actually, you could also get a different set of subsequences $\mathcal{Y}^{(1)}$, $\mathcal{Y}^{(2)}$, $\dots$ converging only to the numbers $1/2^n$ for $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$ because you can use up all the negative values of $\sin(n)$ (as well as all the values greater than $1/2$) as first elements of new subsequences.